# Linq results to a var does not populate values unless refreshed manually

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I have this code fragment which returns specific records from a dataset.

```
DataTable tblr = new DataTable("itemsToValidate");

            tblr.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("QtyOrdered", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("UOM", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("PriceQuoted", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("RequiredBy", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("ExpectedOnDock", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("BackOrdered", typeof(string));

            var records = (from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
                           join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<Nullable<int>>("Loop_Id")
                           equals (t2.Field<Nullable<int>>("Loop_Id"))
                           select  tblr.LoadDataRow(new object[]{ 
                       //                    Position,                  ItemCode,              qtyOrdered,              UOM,         PriceQtd,                   RequiredBy,            Net,status
                               t1.Field<string>("PO101"),t1.Field<string>("PO109"),t1.Field<string>("PO102"),t1.Field<string>("PO103"),t1.Field<string>("PO104"),t2.Field<string>("DTM02"),null,null },false )
                           );
        IEnumerable<DataRow>  x = records.Select( y=>y);
            tblr.AcceptChanges();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(tblr);
            string ItemsXml = ds.GetXml();
```

Unless I set a break point immediately after "records" and refresh the result view, the table (tblr) do not get populated.
How could I populate the tblr without this intervention ?

p.s:

Here is the modified code fragment to include correction suggested by Tim Schmelter,Note that I have used additional select count statement instead of foreach iterator.

```
DataTable tblr = new DataTable("itemsToValidate");

            tblr.Columns.Add("Position", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("QtyOrdered", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("UOM", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("PriceQuoted", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("RequiredBy", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("ExpectedOnDock", typeof(string));
            tblr.Columns.Add("BackOrdered", typeof(string));

            var records = (from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
                           join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable() on t1.Field<int?>("Loop_Id")
                           equals (t2.Field<int?>("Loop_Id"))
                           select  tblr.LoadDataRow(new object[]{ 
                       //                    Position,                  ItemCode,              qtyOrdered,              UOM,         PriceQtd,                   RequiredBy,            Net,status
                               t1.Field<string>("PO101"),t1.Field<string>("PO109"),t1.Field<string>("PO102"),t1.Field<string>("PO103"),t1.Field<string>("PO104"),t2.Field<string>("DTM02"),null,null },false )
                           );
            var x = (from n in records select n).Count();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select` is executed lazily, you have to use a `foreach` or another method that executes the query like `Count`. But i would simply use a `foreach` loop to add the rows from the query via `table.Rows.Add` instead of `LoadDataRow`. A LINQ query is not supposed to cause side effects like adding rows:

```
var records = from t1 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["PO1"].AsEnumerable()
              join t2 in x12.InterchangeDataSet.Tables["DTM"].AsEnumerable() 
              on t1.Field<int?>("Loop_Id") equals t2.Field<int?>("Loop_Id")
              select new {
                PO101 = t1.Field<string>("PO101"),
                PO109 = t1.Field<string>("PO109"),
                PO102 = t1.Field<string>("PO102"),
                PO103 = t1.Field<string>("PO103"),
                PO104 = t1.Field<string>("PO104"),
                DTM02 = t2.Field<string>("DTM02")
             };

foreach(var x in records)
{
    DataRow newRow = tblr.Rows.Add();
    newRow.SetField(0, x.PO101);
    newRow.SetField(1, x.PO109);
    newRow.SetField(2, x.PO102);
    newRow.SetField(3, x.PO103);
    newRow.SetField(4, x.PO104);
    newRow.SetField(5, x.DTM02);       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with ADO.NET (?) but it seems that you have to enumerate IEnumerable which returns from

```
records.Select(y=> y);
```

LINQ allows you to do it with methods like `.ToList()`, `.First()`, etc. Take a look at LINQ lazy evaluations.